# Get History from SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I am developing a Java app in which I run some queries to system tables of SQL Server. Now I want to know from SQL Server Management Studio what queries are run on a particular database and time for execution of that query and status of query result like query execution fail or running or successfully executed.

How can I get this result from SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

if you want old history, you can get it from plan cache,but this will be not accurate if your server was rebooted ..

you can try to improvise below query with columns you need.This will give you queries which ran ,count,cpu time,memory grant

```
select txt.text,ec.execution_count,ec.max_worker_time,ec.max_grant_kb 
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats ec
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
```

further you can use extended events as well to audit all the queries and save them to file for later analysis,this info will be persisted even when server is rebooted